# How to make Diffie Hellman connection between client(CryptoJS) and server(Crypto Node.js)

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to make connection between server and client. I create ECDH keys with elliptic.js and try to cipher-decipher messages. Secret keys are equal both on server and on client. Between servers everything is ok, but between server and client there are a lot of problems.

I have worked a lot to make the client to decipher messages from server. But I can't make right ciphering on client. Server doesn't understand it. Even the client doesn't understand it.

My client uses Crypto JS (I tried to use forge and sjcl but they was much herder for me to understand) and server uses Crypto.
There are my functions on client:

```js
cipherData(data, secret){       
  let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, secret).toString();
  return encrypted;
}

decipherData(encryptedData, secret) {
  let data;
  try {
      //make tranformations because of little features in crypto (node) - it uses empty salt array
      let ct = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedData);
      let salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(0); // empty array
      data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: ct, salt: salt}, secret);
      data = data.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error decrypting data: ' + e)
  }
  return data;
}
```

There is my code on server:

```js
cipherData(data, secret, algorithm = 'aes256'){
  const cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, secret);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(data,'utf8', 'hex');
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return encrypted;
}

decipherData(encryptedData, secret, algorithm = 'aes256'){
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, secret);
  let data = decipher.update(encryptedData,'hex', 'utf8');
  data += decipher.final('utf8');
  return data;
}
```

Maybe someone could help me?
Computed secret key for example(in hex): e6922091e78adce7cff10e01b4eb949317e56ece3597a7daa23c819c6882a955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many attempts I desided to remake server-side using Crypto-JS too. That decision was completely right. All working fine.

```js
    cipherData(data, secret) {
        let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, secret).toString();
        let b64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted);
        encrypted = b64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
        return encrypted;
    }

    decipherData(encryptedData, secret) {
        let data;
        try {
            let b64 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedData);
            let bytes = b64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
            data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(bytes, secret);
            data = data.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error decrypting data: ' + e)
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't be implementing your own DH because I bet you've done that part wrong: most implementations by non-cryptographers are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle.  Second, there is no reason to do any of this: just use TLS.  Third, CryptoJS does not interoperate with many other libraries unless you use the API in the raw format (don't use the password based encryption -- which you appear to be using with your hard coded all zero salt, which is also not good).

Comment: I didn' implement my own DH I just used two libraries for different parts of the algorithm. Elliptic for key generation and cryptoJS for ciphering. Is this wrong? Could you tell me why TLS is better?

Comment: It is wrong if you do Diffie Hellman without authentication because an attacker can swap keys and perform man-in-the-middle.  Even if you take care for this, you still need to serve your JavaScript securely to the client via TLS or the attacker will just inject his own malicious payload there.  So at the end of the day, you still need to fall back to TLS to make it not trivially attackable.  TLS does everything for you already so no need to add an extra layer which can only make things worse: a chain is only as strong as its weakest link.